# Positioning svgs into a box

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox, grid

Right now they are just in a horizontal line.

How would I put them in a grid, box like shape?

I have not been able to figure out how to do this.

Can someone show me how to do it?

Position the svg's in a box like shape.

I tried using grid to do it and I wasn't able to figure it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/xn2s30yc/

[image]

```js
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
    const config = {};

    function show(el) {
        el.classList.remove("hide");
    }

    function hide(el) {
        el.classList.add("hide");
    }

    function hideAll(elements) {
        elements.forEach(hide);
    }

    function showCovers(playButton) {
        const cover = playButton.parentElement;
        cover.classList.add("active");
        show(cover);
    }

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        hideAll(config.containers);
        const cover = evt.currentTarget;
        showCovers(cover);
    }

    function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
        playButtons.forEach(function addEventHandler(playButton) {
            playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
        });
    }

    function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
        const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
        cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
    }

    function init(selectors) {
        config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
        const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
        addClickToButtons(playButtons);
    }

    return {
        addCoverHandler,
        init,
        show
    };
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
    const players = [];

    const tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        const player = event.target;
        player.setVolume(100);
    }

    function addPlayer(video, settings, videoIds = video.dataset.id) {
        const videoId = !Array.isArray(videoIds) && videoIds;
        const playlist = Array.isArray(videoIds) && videoIds;
        const config = {
            host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
            videoId
        };
        config.playerVars = {
            playlist: playlist || undefined
        };

        config.events = {
            "onReady": onPlayerReady
        };
        const defaultOptions = config;
        const playerOptions = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, settings);
        players.push(new YT.Player(video, playerOptions));
    }

    return {
        addPlayer
    };
}());


const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {
    const config = {
        height: 600,
        width: 360
    };
    config.playerVars = {
        autoplay: 0,
        controls: 1,
        disablekb: 1,
        enablejsapi: 1,
        fs: 0,
        iv_load_policy: 3,
        rel: 0
    };

    function show(el) {
        el.classList.remove("hide");
    }

    function createPlayerOptions(settings) {
        function paramInOptions(opts, param) {
            if (settings[param] !== undefined) {
                opts[param] = settings[param];
                delete settings[param];
            }
            return opts;
        }

        const optionParams = ["width", "height", "playlist", "host", "videoid"];
        const defaultOptions = config;
        const preferred = optionParams.reduce(paramInOptions, {});
        const playerOptions = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, preferred);
        // settings should now only consist of playerVars
        const defaultVars = config.playerVars;
        const playerVars = settings.playerVars;
        config.playerVars = Object.assign({}, defaultVars, playerVars);
        return playerOptions;
    }

    function createPlayer(videoWrapper, settings = {}, videoIds = "") {
        const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
        if (!videoIds) {
            videoIds = video.dataset.id;
        }
        const playerOptions = createPlayerOptions(settings);
        return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, playerOptions, videoIds);
    }

    function createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings, videoIds) {
        return function coverClickHandler(evt) {
            const cover = evt.currentTarget;
            const wrapper = cover.nextElementSibling;
            show(wrapper);
            const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerSettings, videoIds);
            wrapper.player = player;
        };
    }

    function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerSettings, videoIds) {
        const clickHandler = createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings, videoIds);
        manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, clickHandler);
    }


    function addPlayerRandomVideo(coverSelector, playerSettings, videoIds) {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * videoIds.length);
        const videoId = videoIds[index];
        const clickHandler = createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings, videoId);
        manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, clickHandler);
    }


    function init(playerOptions) {
        Object.assign(config, playerOptions);
    }

    return {
        add: addPlayer,
        addRandom: addPlayerRandomVideo,
        init
    };
}());


function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    managePlayer.init({
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: 0
        }
    });
    managePlayer.addRandom(".playa", {
        height: 207,
        start: 45,
        width: 277
    }, [
        "0dgNc5S8cLI",
        "mnfmQe8Mv1g",
        "-Xgi_way56U",
        "CHahce95B1g"
    ]);
    managePlayer.add(".playb", {
        height: 207,
        width: 277
    });

    managePlayer.addRandom(".playc", {
        height: 207,
        width: 277
    }, [
        "0dgNc5S8cLI",
        "-Xgi_way56U",
        "CHahce95B1g"
    ]);
    managePlayer.add(".playd", {
        height: 207,
        width: 277
    });

    managePlayer.add(".playe", {
        height: 207,
        width: 277
    });

    managePlayer.add(".playf", {
        height: 207,
        width: 277
    });

    managePlayer.add(".playg", {
        height: 207,
        width: 277
    });
    managePlayer.add(".playh", {
        height: 207,
        width: 277
    });
    managePlayer.add(".playi", {
        height: 207,
        width: 277
    });
    managePlayer.add(".playj", {
        height: 207,
        width: 277
    });
    managePlayer.add(".playk", {
        height: 207,
        width: 277
    });
    managePlayer.add(".playl", {
        height: 207,
        width: 277
    });
    manageCover.init({
        container: ".container",
        playButton: ".thePlay"
    });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
  animation: fade 2s ease 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container.active {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  animation: fadebody 5s ease 0s forwards;
  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(teal 5px, #0000 5px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 5px, #0000 5px), linear-gradient(black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px), linear-gradient(orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px), linear-gradient(black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px), linear-gradient(teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px), linear-gradient(black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px), linear-gradient(orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px), linear-gradient(black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px), linear-gradient(teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px), linear-gradient(black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px), linear-gradient(orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px), linear-gradient(black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px), linear-gradient(teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px), linear-gradient(black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px), linear-gradient(orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px), linear-gradient(black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px), linear-gradient(teal, teal);
}

.thePlay {
  margin: auto 20px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  fill: blue;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}


/* when container is active hide the svg */

.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.inner-container {
  display: none;
}


/* when container is active hide the svg and show the inner container*/

.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.container.active .inner-container {
  display: flex;
}

.container.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes fadebody {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;
  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/26/1920/1080");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.curtain2 .panel-left::before,
.curtain2 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/27/1920/1080");
}

.curtain3 .panel-left::before,
.curtain3 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/27/1920/1080");
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-left {
  animation: curtain1 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain1 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain2 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain2 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes curtain3 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes curtain4 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes curtain5 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes curtain6 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes curtain7 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes curtain8 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes curtain9 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes curtain10 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes curtain11 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes curtain12 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playa thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <g id="play">
        <title>Play</title>
        <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
          M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
      </g>
    </svg>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain1">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playb thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain2">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapb">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="0dgNc5S8cLI"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playc thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain3">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapc">
          <div class="video video-frame"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playd thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain4">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapc">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="0dgNc5S8cLI"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playe thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain5">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapc">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="0dgNc5S8cLI"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playf thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain6">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapc">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="0dgNc5S8cLI"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playg thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain7">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapc">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="0dgNc5S8cLI"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playh thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain8">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapc">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="0dgNc5S8cLI"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playi thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain9">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapc">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="0dgNc5S8cLI"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playj thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain10">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapc">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="0dgNc5S8cLI"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playk thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain11">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapc">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="0dgNc5S8cLI"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <svg class="playl thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain12">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapc">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="0dgNc5S8cLI"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-left"></div>
        <div class="panel-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Grid**
https://jsfiddle.net/p1fxwdey/1/

```
.outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 110px 110px 110px;
  gap: 0;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer.isOpen {
  display: flex;
}
```

**Added Javascript**

```
document.querySelector(".outer").classList.add("isOpen");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Flex**
https://jsfiddle.net/sL15fyo6/

```
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 390px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  gap: 0;
}
.outer.isOpen {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  align-content: stretch;
}
```

**Added Javascript**

```
document.querySelector(".outer").classList.add("isOpen");
```